# The type or namespace name 'LumenWorks' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I try to add the **LumenWorks** library for using CSV reader in C# unity using NuGet.

I saw this lib on the Package folder but this bug still happens:

[image]

Comment: Does the error show up in Unity console?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure why this happens, but if you want to read a csv you can use a StreamReader. (Here's a short video on how to read a csv file: [link](https://www.bing.com/videos/search?q=unity+how+to+read+csv&docid=608009902857207033&mid=CA9D1E72818BF978A5C3CA9D1E72818BF978A5C3&view=detail&FORM=VIRE))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should copy LumenWorks.Framework.IO.dll from Packages to Assets\Plugins